# Libgdx Sprite crossing screen edge

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to implement a smooth transition when my sprite is exiting the screen. This means that if my sprite exits the screen from the left edge, it should appear on the right edge. The main problem that I am having is that I don't want to simply set the new coordinates of the sprite from one edge to another. For example, if the sprite is half through the left edge, the other half should appear on the right edge (smooth transition). Can anyone give any advice for this problem?

Comment: Are you using a SpriteBatch to draw your sprites? If yes, you could simply draw your sprite two times - one leaving to the left and one entering from right.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode!

```
if(sprite.pos.x > screen.width)
{
    sprite.pos.x -= screen.width;
}
else if(sprite.pos.x < 0 - sprite.width)
{
    sprite.pos.x += screen.width;
}

if(sprite.pos.x + sprite.width > screen.width && sprite.pos.x < screen.width)
{
    batch.draw(sprite.texture, sprite.pos.x - screen.width, sprite.pos.y);
} 
else if(sprite.pos.x < 0 && sprite.pos.x + sprite.width > 0)
{
    batch.draw(sprite.texture, sprite.pos.x + screen.width, sprite.pos.y);
}

batch.draw(sprite.texture, sprite.pos.x, sprite.pos.y);
```